# substituting variable to second order derivative in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I am using sympy to derive some equations and I experience some unexpected behaviour with substituting. Let's say I have a function f(x) that I differentiate by x like this:

`fx = f(x).diff()`

This results in the following:

[image]

Now if I substitute x with a value such as pi, like this:

`fx.subs(x, pi)`

I get:

[image]

However, if I substitute x with another variable, let say phi, like this:

`fx.subs(x, phi)`

I get something unexpected:

[image]

What is happening is that sympy is replacing x in the equation before differentiating, I would like that it does after it. I have seen some suggestions that I should use .doit(), but that does not result in a wanted solution:

`fx.doit().subs(x, phi)`

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I replace the variable after the differentiation?

Comment: What exactly would be the difference? It is still the derivative of `f` evaluated at the point `phi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `srepr` to see the structure of an expression more directly:

```
In [48]: f(x).diff(x).subs(x, pi)
Out[48]: 
⎛d       ⎞│   
⎜──(f(x))⎟│   
⎝dx      ⎠│x=π

In [49]: srepr(f(x).diff(x).subs(x, pi))
Out[49]: "Subs(Derivative(Function('f')(Symbol('x')), Tuple(Symbol('x'), Integer(1))), Tuple(Symbol('x')), Tuple(pi))"
```

So you can see that `Subs` is what is used to represent an *unevaluated* substitution:

```
In [50]: Subs(f(x).diff(x), x, phi)
Out[50]: 
⎛d       ⎞│   
⎜──(f(x))⎟│   
⎝dx      ⎠│x=φ
```

Then `doit` is used to make the `Subs` *evaluate* (by performing the substitution):

```
In [51]: Subs(f(x).diff(x), x, phi).doit()
Out[51]: 
d       
──(f(φ))
dφ
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#subs